# How to customise Shoreditch?

Tags: shoreditch

When I do a contact search with the default layout my screen shows 13 contacts - I then have to scroll to see the rest.  When using Shoreditch, I can see only 4 contacts before scrolling because so much of the screen is taken up with title,  header and other areas that are generous in size & perhaps not optimally located.  This is on a newish laptop with a 15.4" HD screen (1920px x 1080), which must be a pretty common device.  This is using Firefox, full screen.  With Chrome, full screen, only 2 contacts are visible before you have to scroll!  My guess is that the developers of Shoreditch have 26" screens on which the layout probably looks great!!   But it really doesn't suit a smaller screen and for that reason I wouldn't change my clients to Shoreditch.  Is there a way it can be customised to fix this problem ? - apart from tinkering with the CSS, that is. With Coleman's wonderful summary screen layout extension depending on Shoreditch, Civi may be unwittingly going down a route of excluding itself from smaller screens, like my laptop - and my client's laptops. That would be a bad mistake.
By the way, in case you're thinking, 'make the font smaller' when I do this to the point where I can still just read the screen, I now can see only 7 contacts!

Comment: Note that the Contact Summary Editor no longer requires Shoreditch. But it does still work well with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your question appears to be:

> When using Shoreditch, I can see only 4 contacts before scrolling. Is there a way it can be customised - apart from tinkering with the CSS, that is?

Shoreditch does nothing but modify the look of CiviCRM via CSS. So, if you're unhappy with the out-of-the-box layout, CSS is what you'll have to use to modify it.

FWIW, my opinion is that http://thereisnopagefold.com/ but I agree that Shoreditch still needs to implement some responsive design for smaller screens. I'm guessing that one of the issues holding this back is that core templates need to be modified to achieve this.

Comment: I don't have CSS skills & neither will a lot of Civi clients so that's not always a workable solution.  But I had an email from one of the Shoreditch developers who said they were thinking about a project to have a 'compact', 'regular' etc layouts (similar to gmail). A 'make it happen' would be opened to fund it, so I'm keeping an eye out for that, as that sounds like a good direction.

Comment: IMO, different layout options seems like a different issue to the need for responsive design. Good to hear there's some thinking around this issue however.